# (real) unipotent subgroup is always generated by one parameter unipotent subgroups?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a connected real Lie group and $H$ be any unipotent subgroup of $G$. I heard from a talk there is a statement saying that $H$ can always be generalized by one parameter subgroups. I wonder if such statement is necessarily true and how to prove it.

---

I am okay if you add additional assumptions like "semisimple without compact factors" if such conditions are necessary.

Comment: What role is the ambient group $G$ playing? Also, what do you meant generated by one-parameter subgroups? Trivially, for any $x\in\mathfrak h$ the group $\exp(\mathbb R x)$ is a one-parameter subgroup of $H$ and together they generate $H$.